# Read parent variable from an cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain-policy

i know there is a lot of ask about cross domain iframe but i definetly can solve my problem which is :

On page www.domain_A.com/test.php

```
<div id="test">this what i want</div>
<iframe src="http://www.domain_B.com/iframe.html" width="500" height="300" name="myFrame" id="myFrame" style="border:1px solid black;"></iframe>
```

And www.domain_B.com/iframe.html is this :

```
document.domain = "www.multipress.fr";
test = document.getElementById('test'); ;
alert(test);
```

So i'd like to alert : this is what i want. But as you guess i get security error from Chrome.

So the only solution i see is to integer a script before the iframe to use the postMessage technics. But before do that, i'd rather check with you if i can find an other solution.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can access from the parent page is the Iframe tag itself - nothing from inside is available when it is pointing to a different domain.

Comment: so you confirm that i need to use postMessage in an other script ?

Comment: Use a server-side proxy. Désolé.

Comment: Browser security was set up this way for a very good reason, otherwise Iframes would be the security back-door for all kinds of malware.

Comment: i think i can do my trick with a temporary table with an integer script then do my true record with the iframe.